# Generate files and ZIP without memory stream

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to store files in a zip file without a memory stream. My goal is to save a maximum of system memory, while direct disk IO is no problem. 
I iterate over a database result set where I have collected some blobs. These are byte-arrays.

What I do it the following (System.IO.Compression):

```
using (var archive = ZipFile.Open("data.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        string fileName = $"{result.Id}.bin";

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            // write the blob data from result.Value
            fileStream.Write(result.Value, 0, result.Value.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileName, fileName);
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems with this implementation.

1. I have my *.bin files AND the one *.zip (only need the zip)
2. I don't know why, but this uses a lot of RAM (~100MB for 15x1.5MB bin files)

Is there a way to completely bybass the memory?

**UPDATE:**

What I'm trying to achieve is to generate one ZIP file that contains single binary files generated from database blobs. This should happen inside a ASP.NET Web API controller. A user can request the data, but instead of sending the whole data in the HTTP response, I generate the ZIP file in the time of the request, save it to a local file server and send a download link back to the user.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve - if you don't want to create a file with `...bin`, why are you creating a new `FileStream` which is explicitly creating that file?

Comment: it helps to check what the CLR is actually doing by checking your calls with ILSPY. But for me neither not clear what you try to achieve

Comment: @JonSkeet I need a zip file with single bin files in it. Maybe (and I hope) there is a more elegant solution, e.g. creating single ZipEntriey objects for every database result. By I need to do it without memory consumption. So creating files on the filesystem seems to be a good start. Otherwise I have to keep them in memory. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well what confuses me is why you're surprised that the `.bin` files exist, when you've created them... you could delete them afterwards, of course...

Comment: Zip archiver consumes a lot of memory during work.

Answer (score -1):

I think your >100 MBs coming from

1. the `results` object which should contain at least 15x1.5 MB of blob data
2. holding the resulting data.zip open inside the foreach Scope.

to minimize the RAM amount of the worker process:

```
create empty zip-file
do {
 (single BLOB query from DB)
 (write blob to new or overwrite File)
 (open zip file for append)
 (append file to zip)
 (close and dispose **both** file handles / objects )
}
```